# Does JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state)) guarantee no mutation of redux state?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux, state

I've been tracking down an issue where a redux store correctly updates, but the component does not reflect the change. I've tried multiple ways of making sure I'm not mutating the state, however the issue persists. My reducers commonly take the form:

```
case 'ADD_OBJECT_TO_OBJECT_OF_OBJECTS': {
    newState = copyState(state);
    newState.objectOfObjects[action.id] = action.obj;
    return newState;
}
```

For my copyState function, I usually use nested Object.assign() calls, but avoiding errors isn't so straightforward. For testing, to make sure I'm not mutating state, is it correct to use

```
const copyState = (state) => {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
};
```

as a guaranteed method of not mutating (redux) state, regardless of how expensive the process is?

If not, are there any other deep copy methods that I can rely on for ensuring I'm not mutating state?

EDIT:
Considering that other people might be having the same issue, I'll relay the solution to the problem I was having.

I was trying to dispatch an action, and then in the line after, I was trying to access data from the store that was updated in the previous line.

```
dispatchAction(data) // let's say this updates a part of the redux state called 'collection'
console.log(this.props.collection) // This will not be updated!
```

Refer to https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1543

Comment: `state` will be untouched in `copyState`

Comment: It would be possible (but incredibly dumb) to give `state` a `.toJSON` method that mutates it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this does a deep clone, regardless of how expensive it is. The difficulty (as hinted in comment under the question) is to make sure `state` stays untouched everywhere else.

Since you're asking for other approaches, and that would not fit in a comment, I suggest to take a look at [ImmutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/), which eliminates the issue of tracking state mutation bugs (but might come with its own limitations):

```
const { Map } = require('immutable')
const map1 = Map({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 })
const map2 = map1.set('b', 50)
map1.get('b') // 2
map2.get('b') // 50
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However I want to make sure I don't have a fundamental misunderstanding of redux. You mentioned 'make sure state stays untouched everywhere else.'

To test, I used this JSON.parse() approach in every single reducer. Still, the store updates correctly (middleware displays changes in 'nextState' after action dispatch) but the component does not reflect these changes.

Does this mean that the problem is for sure NOT redux requiring a non-mutated state, or am I misunderstanding something about how redux works in this implementation of copyState?

Comment: Given the available information I think you are not misunderstanding... and I hope I am not either :) I'm also a beginner about redux, but we can safely say your `copyState` function offers the correct guarantees (regardless of its performance). So the problem seems to be elsewhere :/

Comment: I'd also recommend `deepCopy` from `lodash` instead of the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state))` method, primarily because lodash's deepCopy preserves `Date` objects while the `parse(stringify(state))` will leave you with strings instead of `Date` objects.

Answer (score 3):

Your copyState() function will NOT mutate your state. It is fine. And for others reading this question, it is also fine to directly go

```
const newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldState));
```

to get a deep copy. Feels unclean, but it is okay to do.

The reason you're not seeing your subscriptions run may be that Redux compares the new state (the output of the reducer function) to the existing state before it copies it. If there are no differences, it doesn't fire any subscriptions. Hence the reason that we never mutate state directly but return a copy -- if we did mutate state, changes would never be detected.

Another reason might be that we don't know what dispatchAction() in your code does exactly. If it is async (maybe because of middleware?) the changes wouldn't be applied until *after* your console.log() on the next line.